# How do I get the ServiceM8 iOS app to open PDFs that are attached via the API?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am able to attach PDFs to servicem8 via the API.
The PDFs are valid PDFs and open fine on desktops.
The PDF can be saved from the ServiceM8 diary and attached to the diary.
This same PDF will open when attached to the diary manually, but not when attached via the API.

I note that when saving the PDF after having been attached via the API, the file name begins with dbo and looks like a UUID with no ".pdf" extension.

It is my theory that the issue lies therein.  I.e. ServiceM8 won't open PDFs that do not have the ".pdf" file extension.

Is there a way around this?
Ollie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is going on here;

- ```
  "NLE Only Workings #".$qid." $".number_format($_SESSION["totalfee"],2)
  ```

Is landing you with:

- ```
  "attachment_name":"NLE","file_type":"."‌
  ```

Resolve your file name into a variable first, and then percent-encode it so you end up with a proper request and a debuggable program;

**Example (using cURL)**

- ```
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "related_object=job&active=true&related_object_uuid=cf8ca6dd-ea39-433d-9f90-e0f91cbcf8df&attachment_name=Some%20_%20Rediculously%20%24Silly.file.name_that_i%27d_never%20%60use.pdf&file_type=.pdf"
  ```

**Result:**

- ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: max-age=0
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
  Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.6.22
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.22
  x-record-uuid: 25681082-8182-4d54-b5e5-f11858bcc336
  transfer-encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  ```

Then using **GET** on that that uuid:

- ```
  [
    {
      "uuid": "25681082-8182-4d54-b5e5-f11858bcc336",
      "edit_date": "2016-10-31 13:12:29",
      "active": 1,
      "attachment_name": "Some _ Rediculously $Silly.file.name_that_i'd_never `use.pdf",
      "file_type": ".pdf",
      "attachment_source": "",
      "lng": 0,
      "lat": 0,
      "tags": "",
      "created_by_staff_uuid": "0a059298-02e4-4452-8280-ab89ec871dc8",
      "timestamp": "2016-10-31 13:12:29",
      "related_object": "job",
      "related_object_uuid": "cf8ca6dd-ea39-433d-9f90-e0f91cbcf8df"
    }
  ]
  ```

Notice that the `attachment_name` is the full file name **including extension**.  I would say the `file_type` parameter is used as an internal method to display the attachment in the job diary as intended.  Regardless, the `attachment_name` is what is associated with the attachment `uuid`.

I tested this example to make sure a pdf previews properly using the mobile app as well as the website.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, we'd moved on to other aspects of our system by the time you replied.  You've solved it - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is caused by a missing file extension, you should be able to resolve it by ensuring that the file extension is set correctly.

When you create the attachment via the API (i.e. when you POST to https://servicem8.com/api_1.0/attachment.json) make sure you are setting the `file_type` property to `.pdf`.

Note that you need to include the period prefix: `.pdf` is correct, `pdf` is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am using .pdf; `$fields = array(
     "related_object"=>"job",
     "related_object_uuid"=> $jobuuid,
     "attachment_name"=> "NLE Only Workings #".$qid." $".number_format($_SESSION["totalfee"].".pdf",2),
     "file_type"=> ".pdf",
     "active"=> "true");`

Comment: Looks like you have `.pdf` in there twice, that's pretty likely to cause problems. Try this:

`$fields = array( "related_object"=>"job", "related_object_uuid"=> $jobuuid, "attachment_name"=> "NLE Only Workings #".$qid." $".number_format($_SESSION["totalfee"],2), "file_type"=> ".pdf", "active"=> "true");`

Also post the JSON of the attachment after you've submitted it (i.e. what do you get when you request `https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/dboAttachment/[your attachment uuid].json`)

Comment: Hey :) So that didn't help.  I also shortened the filename to remove any decimal points (from the price etc). no good.  Looking at the file in ServiceM8 on iOS, it doesn't have a PDF extension.  However, upon opening the file in Google Drive from iOS, Google Drive does recognise it as a PDF and I can open it from there...

Comment: The CURL response for the attachment...`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.22
x-record-uuid: 15d8a15e-9797-4548-b718-da78da95080b
Content-Length: 284
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>200 OK</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>OK</h1>
        <p></p>
        <hr />
        <address>ServiceM8/1</address>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: That looks like the response you'd get when POSTing to create the attachment. Have a look at the GET response when you fetch the dboAttachment record from the API. Check the file_type property of the JSON response. For PDF files it should be set to `.pdf` (including the leading dot).

Comment: The 'file_type' comes back as ".".  I've tried several permutations, including ".PDF","pdf",".pdf", using .pdf on the filename, not using .pdf on the filename - no matter what I do, it seems to come back as "."??
`{"uuid":"a2174142-be96-4092-8aba-99e98688a33b","edit_date":"2016-09-22 10:09:20","active":1,"attachment_name":"NLE","file_type":".","attachment_source":"","lng":0,"lat":0,"tags":"","created_by_staff_uuid":"5106124d-a45d-4b0c-97c5-7335ae275d1f","timestamp":"2016-09-22 10:09:19","related_object":"job","related_object_uuid":"a7e2880f-e72c-49a2-a4d2-0a08fa61d2db"}`

Comment: yo got anything for me?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the file_type field to be blank, but that's definitely the cause of the other issues you're describing. If you can send me a request/response log or Postman screenshot of what you're doing to update the file_type field, I'll do my best to see what the issue is.